# Normal operators, verification

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras, adjoint-operators

I have been reading some article and I came across this equality
$$\big\| |T|+|T^*|\big\|^2 = \big\|(\,|T|+|T^{*}|\,)^2\big\|\,,$$
where $|T|=(T^{*}T)^{\frac12}$. The only way this can hold is if the operator under the norm is a normal operator, that is I believe for normal operators it holds that
$$\|T\|^{n}=\|T^n\|$$
The author didn't state this, or even mention it, but I believe it to be the case. I mean, if $T_1=|T|+|T^*|$, then it holds that $T_1^*=T_1$. This holds because
$$|T|^*=|T|$$
and $|T^*|^*=|T^*|$. Then checking the condition whether $T_1$ is normal, we get
$$T_{1}^{*}T_{1}=T_{1}T_{1}^{*}$$
and it is the same, therefore $T_1$ is normal and we can use the fact $$\|T^n\|=\|T\|^n\,.$$
Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author possibly did not state or mention it, because the bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space form a $C^*$-algebra, in which you always enjoy the $C^*$*-property:* $\:$this is the equality
$$\|a^*a\| = \|a\|^2\,\;\forall\, a\,.$$
Thus, $\|a^2\| = \|a\|^2,\;$ whenever $a$ is self-adjoint.

$|T|$, and $|T^*|$, and their sum $|T|+|T^*\,|$ are self-adjoint operators. Which are normal operators in particular, so yes, you are correct.